# Deferred Execution (IQueryable) to database level without using ORM?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any easy reasonable/feasible way to efficiently pipeline results from the database?

I can't use any ORM tools. I believe LINQ-SQL does this with it's queryable interfaces which is what I wish to do here.

Comment: Yes. I was mentioning it as probably providing functionality which I wish to imitate.

Comment: Imitate but in a non ORM way?  Can you explain that a bit it does not really make sense to me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  Do you just need to get some data?  or is 'efficiently pipeline' something specific I'm not familiar with?  Maybe a fake example of code that you want to write would help us?

Comment: Just curious, but why can't you use any ORM tools?

Comment: I want "deferred execution", but to the database. However after thinking about it, I am guessing the only way to do this would be to request one record at a time from the database which for situations needing large data set would result in far too many query calls to the database. I wanted to have filtering occur in our application and not have to get the whole table at once or confine the filtering logic into Stored procedures as we are dynamically injecting filter logic. After some thought, my question not be answerable with reasonable constaints...although I am curious how L2SQL handles it.

Comment: Because our current standards in the environment do not currently allow for it. There was some technical problems with our existing implementation and ORM when it was looked at.

Comment: How would you get the results back, if not as objects?

Comment: @Joshua  LinqToSql converts expression trees into SQL statements.  The SQL is executed when you Enumerate the collection so you can just keep adding to the query and it generates the sql only when you iterate through the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to the comments above, I think that what youre looking for is the LAZY LOAD PATTERN.

In few words, Martin F. describes this pattern as "An object that doesn't contain all of the data you need but knows how to get it."

So follow these links to learn more:
[WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading),
[MARTIN FOWLER](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html)

Comment: Proxy is another relevant pattern